# SwiftでPHPにMultiPartPostでデータを渡したい

Tags: swift, php, 画像

Swiftでテキストデータと画像データをPHPにPOSTしたいと思っています．

テキストデータは渡せたのですが，画像データを渡すところができていません．
※DateやUserIDなどの情報はデータベースに追加されているのを確認済みです．画像も同様に別データベースに追加されるはずですができていません．

そもそもPHPの知識があまりなく，画像データで渡さなければいけない情報がこれで合っているのかも分からない状態です．

おそらく，送る画像データに複数のパラメータも送らないといけないかと思います（type?など）

画像に関するデータのPOSTする方法が分かる方がいましたら，お教えいただければ幸いです．

**取れているデータ**

```
201910182027273320
Optional(405797 bytes)
パラメーター：["Name": "papapa", "UserID": "pepepe", "Comment": "pooooooooo", "Platform": "Xcode", "Date": "201910182027273320", "file": Optional(<UIImage: 0x600003bce060>, {472, 384}), "type": "image/png"]
<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x6000010e5320> { URL: PHPのURL } { Status Code: 403, Headers {
    "Accept-Ranges" =     (
        bytes
    );
    Connection =     (
        "keep-alive"
    );
    "Content-Length" =     (
        1422
    );
    "Content-Type" =     (
        "text/html"
    );
    Date =     (
        "Fri, 18 Oct 2019 11:28:09 GMT"
    );
    "Last-Modified" =     (
        "Wed, 08 Mar 2017 06:08:47 GMT"
    );
    Server =     (
        Apache
    );
} }
parse error
```

**Swift**

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController, URLSessionTaskDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    var json: NSData!

    // 仮でPOSTする情報
    var date = "111"
    var user_id = "pepepe"
    var name = "papapa"
    var comment = "pooooooooo"
    var platform = "Xcode"
    var imageData = UIImage(named: "res2.png")
    var fileName = "image/png"
    let path = "PHPのURL"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.getToday()
        print(date)
    }

    @IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        post()
    }

    // 日付を取得するメソッド
    func getToday(format: String = "yyyyMMddHHmmssSSSS") {
        let now = Date()
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = format
        date = formatter.string(from: now as Date)
    }

    // PHPにPOSTする
    func post() {

        let client = APIClient()
        let parameters:[String: Any]  = ["file": imageData , "type": fileName, "Date": date, "UserID": user_id, "Name": name, "Comment": comment, "Platform": platform]
        client.multipartPost(urlString: path, parameters: parameters)

        print("パラメーター：\(parameters)")
    }
}

extension NSMutableData {
    func appendString(_ string: String) {
        let data = string.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)
        append(data!)
    }
}

class APIClient {

    func multipartPost(urlString: String, parameters: [String: Any]) {

        let url = URL(string: urlString)
        var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"

        let (headers, body) = APIClient.createMultiPartPost(parameters: parameters)

        // ヘッダーの設定
        for header in headers {
            request.addValue(header.value, forHTTPHeaderField: header.key)
        }

        // Bodyの設定
        request.httpBody = body

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            if let data = data, let response = response {
                print(response)
                do {
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments)
                    print(json)
                } catch {
                    print("parse error")
                }
            } else {
                print(error ?? "unknown error")
            }
        }

        task.resume()
    }

    static func createMultiPartPost(parameters: [String: Any]) -> (headers: [String:String], body: Data) {

        let uniqueId = UUID().uuidString
        let boundary = "---------------------------\(uniqueId)"

        let header = [
            "Content-Type" : "multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)"
        ]

        var body = Data()

        let boundaryText = "--\(boundary)\r\n"

        for param in parameters {

            switch param.value {
            case let image as UIImage:

                let imageData = image.pngData()

                print(imageData)

               // let ui8Bytes: [UInt8] = [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
               // let ui8Data = Data(bytes: ui8Bytes)
               // let decodedUi8Bytes = [UInt8](imageData!)

                body.append(boundaryText.data(using: .utf8)!)
                body.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(param.key)\"; filename=\"\(uniqueId).png\"\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
                body.append("Content-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)

                body.append(imageData!.base64EncodedData())
                body.append("\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)

            case let string as String:

                body.append(boundaryText.data(using: .utf8)!)
                body.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(param.key)\";\r\n\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
                body.append(string.data(using: .utf8)!)
                body.append("\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)

            default:
                break
            }
        }

        body.append("--\(boundary)--\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
        return (header, body)
    }
}
```

**PHP**

```php
<?php
    class Data
    {
        public function AddComment()
        {
          // 別スクリプトからDBへの接続を一括で行う
          require_once('mysql_connect.php');
          $pdo = connectDB();
            $ID;
            $Date    = $_POST["Date"];
            $UserID  = $_POST["UserID"];
            $Name    = $_POST["Name"];
            $Comment = $_POST["Comment"];
            $Img = $_FILES["file"];
            $Platform = $_POST["Platform"];
            $UpdatedAt;

            try{
                // $pdo=new PDO($dnsinfo,$USER,$PW);//接続

                $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);//デバックする処理
                if($pdo==null){
                    die("error");
                }else{
                    print("投稿用DB接続しました");
                }
                $stmt=$pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO 19_comment_data VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
                $res=$stmt->execute(array($ID,$Date,$UserID,$Name,$Comment,$Platform,$UpdatedAt));

                $sql='SELECT * FROM 19_comment_data ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1';
                $stmt=$pdo->prepare($sql);
                $stmt->execute();
                $val= $stmt->fetchAll();
                print($val[0]['id']);

                // アップロードされたファイルがpng形式か確認　効いてなくね？
                if ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png") {
                    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
                        echo "Return Code:" . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "";
                    } else {
                        echo "Upload:" . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "";
                        echo "Type:" . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "";
                        echo "Size:" . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . "Kb";
                        echo "Temp file:" . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "";

                        print($val[0]['id']);

                        // サーバー上に既にファイルが存在していないか確認
                        if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
                            echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "already exists.";
                        } else {
                            // pngに変換する
                            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "upload/" . $val[0]['id'].".png");
                            $image = imagecreatefrompng("upload/" . $val[0]['id'].".png");

                            // pngのaを使えるようにする処理
                            imagealphablending($image, false);
                            imagesavealpha($image, true);

                            // png画像として再保存
                            imagepng($image, "upload/" . $val[0]['id'].".png");
                            imagedestroy($image);
                            echo "Stored in:" . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    echo "Invalid file";
                }

                // リサイズ処理  500kb以上ならリサイズ
                if($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024 > 500)
                {
                  list($width, $hight) = getimagesize("upload/" . $val[0]['id'].".png"); // 元の画像名を指定してサイズを取得
                  $baseImage = imagecreatefrompng("upload/" . $val[0]['id'].".png"); // 元の画像から新しい画像を作る準備
                  // 正方形とかに書き出すことも可能
                  $image = imagecreatetruecolor($width/10, $hight/10); // サイズを指定して新しい画像のキャンバスを作成

                  // 画像のコピーと伸縮
                  imagecopyresampled($image, $baseImage, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width/10, $hight/10, $width, $hight);

                  // コピーした画像を出力する
                  imagepng($image ,"upload/" . $val[0]['id'].".png");
                  imagedestroy($image);
                }

            }catch(PDOException $e)
            {//エラー
                $res=$e->getMessage();
            }

            if($res==TRUE){
                print("投稿success");
            }else if($res==FALSE){
                print("投稿error");
            }

        }
    }

    $obj=new Data();
    $obj->AddComment();

?>
```

Comment: 使われていない変数や拡張メソッド(`appendString(_:)`)があったり、必要のないデータ変換が行われている(`Data`を`[UInt8]`に変換する必要は無い)など、手直ししたくてうずうずしてくるコードですが、大きな問題点は一箇所だけ(PHP側は`image/png`しか受け付けないコードになっているのに、`image/jpeg`でデータを送っている)のように思われます。「画像データを渡すところができていません」なんて言う何が起こっているのかよくわからない書き方ではなく、**現在のコードで画像データを渡そうとすると何が起こるのか** を具体的に書いてください。「Swiftのコードがコンパイル時エラーになって実行できない」「コンパイルはできるが実行時エラーになる」「実行はできるがPHP側からのレスポンスが受信できない」「レスポンスは受信できるが…」??? ご自身の質問は「編集」から内容を修正できますので、ご質問にその辺の情報を詳しく追記してください。

Comment: 無言でコードだけ修正されても何が起こったのかわからないです。「テキストデータは渡せた」が「画像データを渡すところができていません」と判断されたのは、 **一体何をしてどんな結果が返ってきた** からなのでしょうか? 読者はあなたのコードの共同開発者ではありません。あなたがどんな環境で開発を行っているのかも、あなたがアプリをテスト起動する様子も見たことがない人が、何が起こっているのかを理解する手助けになる情報を **詳細に** 提示してください。「おそらく」と言った推測よりも、まずは現在起こっている事実を詳しく正確に伝えることを優先してください。

Comment: ご質問内容の修正ありがとうございました。ある程度可能性を絞り込める程度の情報をいただきましたので、不完全ではあるのですが、回答の形でまとめてみました。一度目を通していただければと思います。なお、ご自身の書いた質問に対してはコメントがつけられるはずですので、質問内容を編集するほどでは無い、と思われる補助的な内容の提示にはコメント機能も活用してください。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

色々情報を付け加えていただいて、問題のありそうな場所が少し絞り込めてきたので、回答の形で書かせていただきたいと思います。

まずは、確認から。

- 現在のSwiftのコードは問題なくビルドできてシミュレータが起動する

  (Xcodeやシミュレータのバージョン、何よりプラットフォームがiOSであることも記載したほうが良いでしょう。)
- シミュレータ上でボタンを押すと、データ送信されていると思われるメッセージがデバッグコンソールに現れる。「**取れているデータ**」としたのは、デバッグコンソールに表示されたもの

  (データの取り方には、色々あります。その取り方をどこにも書かないで、「取れているデータ」として示すより、「デバッグコンソールの表示内容」と書いてもらったほうが、Xcodeに慣れている読者には伝わりやすいです。)
- PHP側では現在質問に表示しているコードでテストしている。上記の1回のテストで、

  1. 同時に送った「DateやUserIDなどの情報はデータベースに追加されているのを確認」
  2. 同時に送った「画像も同様に別データベースに追加されるはず」だができていない

(「テキストデータは渡せた」とだけ書かれても、どのような手順で何を確認したから「渡せた」と判断したのかがわかりません。またテキストデータを渡すだけのテストコードを作った時には動いたと言うことなのか、現在のコードでテキストと画像を送るとテキストだけが「渡せた」のかわかりません。また、「渡せた」と言うあなたの判断ではなく、最新のご質問にあるように「データベースに追加されているのを確認」と言う具体的な確認内容を記載してください。)

さて、長々と書いてきましたが、上記の前提が崩れると、考えうる問題の範囲が大きく広がってしまいますので、もし「それは違う」と言う部分があれば、お早めにお知らせください。

---

さて、まずはSwift側です。以前ご質問の初版に関するコメントで「大きな問題点は一箇所だけ」と書きました。その時のコードは「pngデータではなく、jpegデータを送っている」と言う大きな問題はありましたが、「画像データを送るコードとして(無駄は多いが)正しく動くはず」のものだったのに、現在はそうなっていません。

(なお、コメントをしっかり読んでそれをご質問内容の改善に生かしていただくのは大変良いことだと思うのですが、コードの修正を含む場合、どこにどんな修正を施したのか簡単にでも触れておくと、最初から質問を読んでいる読者にとって読みやすいものになります。)

あなたの現在のコードで致命的に問題があるのはこちら:

```
                body.append(imageData!.base64EncodedData())
```

なぜここでBase-64になんかしてしまっているのでしょうか?multipart/form-dataのコード例でも見かけたことはありません。Content-Transfer-Encodingを指定すればうまくいくかもしれませんが、普通はそんなことはしません。そのまま使いましょう。

```
                body.append(imageData!)
```

これでSwift側の修正は完了です。(「致命的」でない単なる「無駄」については、長くなって本質的な問題がどこかわかりにくくなるので省略します。)このコードで正しく動かないのであれば、それは **PHP側に問題がある** と言うことです。

---

あなたのPHPコードでは手がかりを掴むようなログ出力も行なっていないようなのですが、「DateやUserIDなどの情報はデータベースに追加されているのを確認済み」と言うことなので、その後に何らかの問題があるのだろうと推測できます。

```
                $stmt=$pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO 19_comment_data VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
                $res=$stmt->execute(array($ID,$Date,$UserID,$Name,$Comment,$Platform,$UpdatedAt));

//↑INSERT文の実行までは動いている
//↓これ以降のどこかの行(ここに示した範囲以外を含めて)に問題がある

                $sql='SELECT * FROM 19_comment_data ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1';
                $stmt=$pdo->prepare($sql);
                $stmt->execute();
                $val= $stmt->fetchAll();
                print($val[0]['id']);
                ...
```

またPHP/Apacheから403というエラーコード(Forbidden)が返ってきています。これはPHP/Apacheの設定上「アクセスしちゃいけないところにアクセスしようとした」と言うのを示しています。(これだけではどこをチェックすれば良いのか見当もつきませんが、上記のようにPHP側の上に示したポイント以降を見れば良いはずです。)

そのつもりでPHPのコードを再度よく見直してみると、怪しい箇所が見えてくるのですが、できればもう少し確実な情報が欲しいところです。

Swift側の`APIClient.multipartPost(urlString:parameters:)`内の`print(response)`の後に、次のような1行を付け加えて、どんな出力が得られるか調べてみていただけないでしょうか?

```
                print(response)
                print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) ?? "Unknown encoding") //###
```

Comment: 先ほど解決いたしました．
質問内容の方法など，細かな指摘をありがとうございました

PHPに異常はなく，Swift側でjpgデータをそのままmultipart/formで渡すといけました．
それとサーバーの方に問題があり，ブラウザ上でずっとデータベースに送られているか確認していて，追加されていなかったのですが，フォークリフトをインストールして確認してみると，そちらではデータベースに追加されていました．

Comment: @swsw さん、ご報告ありがとうございます。今回は実質的にご自身で解決できたようですが、通信系の処理なんかは、クライアント側サーバ側双方でちょっとしたミスが重なって、かなりのベテランでも解決が難しいと言う事象がしばしば発生する分野です。次回何かありましたら、コメントや解答中に示した質問の書き方のコツを生かしていただければ幸いです。